# ag-grid 'IToolPanel' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: ag-grid

after updating to version 19 and `ag-grid-community` package. I'm getting following error while running `ng serve`:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ag-grid-angular/src/interfaces.ts(20,5): error TS6133: 'IToolPanel' is declared but its value is never
read.
```

I couldn't find any other stackoverflow question / github issue  created about it.

Comment: error? not warning?

Comment: yes, ng serve marks it as an error.

Comment: Try to re-install 'ag-grid' at all

Comment: @un.spike in v19 there is no `ag-grid` package anymore. Anyway, reinstalling `ag-grid-community` does not help.

Comment: at all - means - all packages (i know about changes) I see that warning but it doesn't influence the app. Provide an `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` file pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens when you have `noUnusedLocals` in your `tsconfig` enabled.

I've reported this to ag-grid team again and they recognized that as a bug. Fix should be released in `v20` version by the end of 2018.